# view open file handlers for a process on windows

Tags: windows, process

I want to view open file handlers for a process on windows to verify the correct config file is read. ProcMon and other tools show referenced modules - dlls. I need to see open file handles to all files such as xml, txt, etc.

Comment: You already mention ProcMon - how about FileMon?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

[Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-gb/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx) can provide this information, though it is hidden by default.

To show handles: `View -> Lower Pane View -> Handles`

Process Explorer also allows you to search on a file name and determine which process has it opened.

Comment: I have Process Explorer too. Where do you see File Handles? I only see Modules.

Comment: @user236215, `View`->`Lower Pane View`->`Handles`.

Comment: Make sure you run as administrator to see processes from all users.

Answer (score 1):

Sysinternal Suite comes with `handle.exe` for dumping within CLI:

```
handle
handle -a
handle -p 10832
```