# How do I fix System.IO.IOException Error?

Tags: vb.net

I am programming a teacher management system and I want to save the teachers name. But I get this error 'System.IO.IOException' The process can't access the file because it's being used by another process.

```
Sub AddTeacher()
        Dim FileName As FileStream
        Dim FileNameWriter As BinaryWriter
        Dim OneTeacher As Teacher
        Dim Answer As String

        FileName = New FileStream("C:\TNSMS\Teachers.dat", FileMode.Create)

        Console.Write("Teacher ID          :")
        OneTeacher.TeacherID = CInt(Console.ReadLine())
        FileNameWriter.Write(OneTeacher.TeacherID)
        Console.Write("Teacher's Gender         :")
        OneTeacher.Gender = CInt(Console.ReadLine())
        FileNameWriter.Write(OneTeacher.Gender)
        Console.Write("Teacher's Age           :")
        OneTeacher.Age = CInt(Console.ReadLine())
        FileNameWriter.Write(OneTeacher.Age)
        Console.Write("Teacher's Name          :")
        OneTeacher.Name = CInt(Console.ReadLine())
        FileNameWriter.Write(OneTeacher.Name)
        Console.Write("Teacher's Subject          :")
        OneTeacher.Subject = CInt(Console.ReadLine())
        FileNameWriter.Write(OneTeacher.Subject)
        Console.Write("Teacher Password (Max 12)          :")
        OneTeacher.Password = CInt(Console.ReadLine())
        FileNameWriter.Write(OneTeacher.Password)

        FileNameWriter.Close()
        FileName.Close()

        Console.WriteLine("Teacher details have been saved!")



        Console.Write("Do you want to add a new teacher? (Y/N)")
        Answer = Console.ReadLine
        If Answer = "Y" Then
            AddTeacher()
        Else

        End If


    End Sub
```

I googled it but I can't find the solution

Comment: This is VB.NET, not VBA...

Comment: Please tell us if you have read and understand the error message - or not - and if not, what part of the error message do you need help with?

Comment: Have a read through this and see if it helps: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/using-statement

Comment: @Dai I just don't understand the part 'because it's being used by another process'. What process is using the .dat file?

Comment: @MarioCoder911 [Use ProcExp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13420057/view-open-file-handlers-for-a-process-on-windows) to find out what other programs/processes have locks on files.

Comment: @Dai I just checked.  It seems that its only my app has a lock on it...

Comment: Did you read the link I posted? Or just ignoring? It answers exactly what your problem is.

Comment: This is not related to your issue but it seems bizarre to use `FileMode.Create` there. You go through that code and create the file, then you ask if the user wants to add a new teacher and, if they say yes, you go through the code again and create a new file, overwriting the one you just created. Also, you should not be calling that method from within itself. You should have a `Do While` loop outside the method that calls it as long as the user keeps answering yes.

Comment: You would be better off creating a CSV file instead of using a BinaryWriter, IMO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For classes that implement `Dispose`, you should initialise them with the `Using` syntax. Particularly when read/writing to the file system, if you don't `Dispose` (or wrap in `Using`) then the file can stay open.

Please note that your current code is overwriting the same file each time. You might want to consider `File.WriteAllText` instead (see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualbasic.fileio.filesystem.writealltext?view=net-7.0)

```
Sub AddTeacher()
  Dim Answer As String
  Do

    Dim OneTeacher As Teacher = New Teacher

    Console.Write("Teacher ID          :")
    OneTeacher.TeacherID = CInt(Console.ReadLine())
    Console.Write("Teacher's Gender         :")
    OneTeacher.Gender = CInt(Console.ReadLine())
    Console.Write("Teacher's Age           :")
    OneTeacher.Age = CInt(Console.ReadLine())
    Console.Write("Teacher's Name          :")
    OneTeacher.Name = CInt(Console.ReadLine())
    Console.Write("Teacher's Subject          :")
    OneTeacher.Subject = CInt(Console.ReadLine())
    Console.Write("Teacher Password (Max 12)          :")
    OneTeacher.Password = CInt(Console.ReadLine())

    Using FileName As New FileStream("C:\junk\Teachers.dat", FileMode.Create)
      Using FileNameWriter As New BinaryWriter(FileName)
        FileNameWriter.Write(OneTeacher.TeacherID)
        FileNameWriter.Write(OneTeacher.Gender)
        FileNameWriter.Write(OneTeacher.Age)
        FileNameWriter.Write(OneTeacher.Name)
        FileNameWriter.Write(OneTeacher.Subject)
        FileNameWriter.Write(OneTeacher.Password)
      End Using
    End Using
    Console.WriteLine("Teacher details have been saved!")
    Console.Write("Do you want to add a new teacher? (Y/N)")
    Answer = Console.ReadLine.ToUpper
  Loop Until Answer <> "Y"
End Sub
```

Comment: Since `End Using` calls `Dispose` the `Close` functions are redundant.

Comment: @Mike You're right! just checked the docs and `.Close` calls are deprecated. I've updated my answer